Matching numbers using Zsh glob operators: difference between '[0-9]' and '<->'
Is there any difference, either practical or not, to use [0-9] or instead <-> to match numbers, when using zmv?
For example, I have tried the following two commands and they seem to work the same. Either one copies all files such as foo1.jpg or bar0053.png to the images directory.
zmv '*<->.(gif|jpg|png)' 'images/'

zmv '*[0-9].(gif|jpg|png)' 'images/'


Do you want to match the single digit before the dot, or the whole number? That's the difference.  Neither pattern uses glob qualifiers.

@Kusalananda Ah, thanks. [0-9] matches a single digit, and <-> matches the whole number, correct?

Well, with the * in front of the patterns, both would match the single digit before the dot. It would only really matter if you had a more restrictive pattern, such as bar<->.png (matches bar0053.png) or bar[0-9].png (would not match bar0053.png).  It depends on what you want to achieve.

[a-b] matches a single character in the range, be it letters or digits.
That, is [0-9] matches e.g. 5, but not in itself 15.
OTOH, <-> matches a (nonnegative) number, like 0, 5, or 123. It's equivalent to [0-9]## (one or more decimal digits for which you need the extendedglob option to be enabled).
More usefully, it can match a range of numbers, even something like 199-201, which is hard to do with character-based matches.
Consider, e.g.
% touch a5b a123b
% echo a[0-9]b
a5b
% echo a<->b
a123b a5b

and
% touch a{198..203}b a000200b
% echo a<199-201>b
a000200b a199b a200b a201b

Of course if you have *[0-9], it'll match anything ending in a digit, including 5, 15 and foo9. Similarly *<-> will match anything ending in a number, which is pretty much the same since single-digit numbers count the same.
(Also there's the caveat that depending on the system and your shell, [0-9] can match more number-like characters than just the usual western digits zero to nine. In zsh, that's guaranteed to be the same as [0123456789] in its globs but not in its regexps (in [[ $string =~ $regexp ]] which uses the system's regex library) unless the rematchpcre option is enabled (which uses PCRE2, formerly PCRE))
